# Help me understand 過去の蓄積 and 面白いと思ってきたもの

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

How do you interpret this? This is an artist talking:

> 一番気にしているのはやっぱり**過去の蓄積**、自分が面白いと思ってきたものでしょうね。**おもしろいと思ってきたもの**には一貫性はあるんですよ、人間の癖がありますからね。だから、昔おもしろいと思ったものを、自分というフィルターを通してもう一回具現化したい、それが今の願望なのかもしれない。

I guess I have two main questions:

1. What exactly is being 蓄積ed -- 過去 or おもしろいと思ってきたもの
2. When you read this, do you understand おもしろいと思ってきたもの as referring to things *he himself* has done in the past, or just anything in general that he liked?

Answer (score 2):

1. 蓄積 here is a *noun* which literally means 'accumulation' but actually means '(accumulated) experience' in this context. 過去の蓄積 means "what I have accumulated", or simply "experience in the past".
2. It depends on his career. If he is a young creator, this should mainly refer to what he has seen as a consumer. If he is a veteran creator who is trying to challenge something new, it probably refers to what he has done as a creator, too.